# Why is npm asking for a password?

Tags: linux, node.js, centos, npm

I'm running a CentOS6.4 virtual box on windows 8 (using vagrant), and I'm trying to install my project's dependencies which include `proto`. I'm running `npm install proto` and it prompts me for a password. WTH? Why would npm prompt me for a password?

https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/3956

Comment: I think it has to do with your setup vagrant/virtual box than npm.

Comment: Yes thanks, that seemed obvious to me too. I believe this must have some weird issue with the shared folder situation in vagrant/virtualbox

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, npm doesn't like the following format on CentOS (and possibly other flavors of linux)

```
git+https://git@github.com/project/blah.git#commit-ish
```

Using the `git` username seems to work fine on windows, but I guess it throws linux for a loop. I ended up switching to using the following format:

```
https://github.com/project/blah/archive/commit-ish.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

You got a repos by [HTTPS cloning with OAuth tokens](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys#https-cloning-with-oauth-tokens). Password is the token and it isn't cached.
You can setup [SSH agent forwarding](https://help.github.com/articles/managing-deploy-keys#ssh-agent-forwarding), so it does not prompt you password.

Comment: Why would I *ever* have to put in a password to install a package via npm? Why would it require someone to have a github account? Can't you clone github repositories without having a github account?

Comment: AFAIK, we need a github account to clone a repos by `ssh`, or `https`. If we do not have account, we can download zip file by web interface or `curl`

Comment: I think it would be useful for organization with private projects. If npm asks username and password or use credentials, only users with the access rights would download it.